# Licenciamento de Jogos Indie

Tags: jogos, licença

Posso vender jogos feitos no Blender sem me preocupar com licenças?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depende do que você chama de "um jogo feito no Blender". De um modo geral, **dados** produzidos/processados por um programa não têm relação alguma com o seu código. Se você escrever um texto no Word, por exemplo, os direitos autorais do mesmo não vão pra Microsoft... De modo que se você usar o Blender pra criar modelos, animações, etc, e usar isso no seu jogo, então não há a necessidade de se preocupar com licenças.

(Do ponto de vista do Blender, é claro - se você usar modelos de outras pessoas como base para os seus próprios, isso caracteriza uma "obra derivada", ou talvez "cópia". Nesse caso, você pode sim precisar negociar um licenciamento com o(s) autor(es) dos modelo utilizados.)

Agora, quando se fala num jogo, tem código envolvido no meio, então a coisa fica mais complicada. No caso do Blender, ele possui uma engine de jogos embutida. Isso significa que você pode criar um jogo completo simplesmente através de scripts, usando essa engine como "o programa" (há inclusive uma opção pra compilar para um executável). Nesse caso, pode haver restrições sobre a forma de você comercializar seu jogo. Por exemplo, como o Blender é software livre, do tipo [*copyleft*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft) (GNU GPL), isso significa que ao redistribuí-lo você deve fazê-lo em termos que a pessoa que recebe tenha as mesmas liberdades que você (obter o código fonte, modificá-lo à vontade, redistribuir pra quem quiser).

Como um jogo feito dessa forma (script da própria engine do Blender)  inclui boa parte do código do Blender, então não se pode dizer que ele é seu - e sim uma obra derivada do próprio Blender. A forma de licenciamento nesse caso é complexa, de modo que eu sugeriria consultar um advogado.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você produzir modelos, animações, simulações físicas em um programa aberto como blender, você poderá exportar em formato mais usado como FBX. Segundo a licença, não poderá comercializar um arquivo que conter formato do blender senão é preciso rever conceito da licença, o blender é um software aberto e livre no termo de uso, não pode usar blender como software para ser comercializado e vendido, isso pode tirar vantagem de blender ser o software livre à todos os usuários. Contudo, ao importar FBX ao unity poderá configurar com todos os script em C# e Javascript e na UI, terá modelos, animações, tudo que foi criado partir de você, caso que não encontre as texturas a partir de FBX, é somente pegando as texturas e arrastando para pasta que tem no asset e integrar no material que é vinculado ao objeto de modelo.
Espero ter ajudado.